# Windows 7 batch file to read filenames from a text file and create the file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file which will have one filename per line.
I want to run a batch file that will;
- read a line
- test to see if the file exists in the current directory
- if not, create the named file in the current directory
in a loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
cd \
cd\"C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Test"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (_list2.txt) do (
echo line=%%a
call "processline %%a
)
goto :eof

If NOT Exist %%a copy _template.xlsm %%a
dir
pause
goto :eof

:eof pause
pause
```

but it doesn't work yet....

Comment: what on earth is `call "processline %%a`

Answer (score -1):

```
cd "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Test"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (_list2.txt) do (
echo line=%%a
call "processline %%a

If NOT Exist %%a copy _template.xlsm %%a
)
```